# Save information of student object to separate .txt file line by line (Python)

Tags: python, class, object, save

(I'm new to Python)

I have created a School class containing a dictionary where I let the user save student objects from a Student class.

```
class School:
    def __init__(self):
        self.students = {}
```

```
class Student:
    def __init__(self, first_name, last_name, ssn)
```

The program starts off by importing information from an already existing .txt file, then the user is given the option to add/delete students or modify the information of the existing ones. When I end the program I want to give the option to "save and exit", so that the changes gets written to either the .txt file it imported the information from or a new one.

I would like the program to write the first name on the first line, the last name on the next line, the social security number on the line after that, and then move on to the following student until all information has been saved.

This is how I would like the program to run:

```
def save_and_exit(original_file):
    ...
    answer = input("Would you like to save to the original file or a new one?")
        if answer in original:
            ... #saves to the same file the imported information came from
        elif answer in new:
            new_file = input("What is the name of the new file?")
            ... #saves to a new file named by the user
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer might be overkill, but let me give you some advice:

- get familiar with dataclasses -> the way to go for classes containing data
- get familiar with fundamental data structures dict + json
- dont invent the wheel by yourself - look for and use ready to go database-solutions for python rather than messing with self-made txt.files for data persistence
- cli is the way to go for so many python scripts. get familiar with it

what you are trying to solve is for me a database with a simple cli.

I suggest looking at these third party modules: [typer](https://typer.tiangolo.com) and [tinydb](https://tinydb.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

with these you can make a "school.py" like this:

```
from dataclasses import asdict, dataclass, field
from tinydb import TinyDB, Query, where
import typer

FILE = "data.json"

app = typer.Typer()


@dataclass
class Student:
    first_name: str
    last_name: str
    ssn: str

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        return Student(**d)


@dataclass
class School:
    name: str
    students: list[Student] = field(default_factory=list)

    @classmethod
    def from_dict(cls, d):
        cls.name = d["name"]
        cls.students = [Student.from_dict(s) for s in d["students"]]
        return cls


@app.command()
def add_student(first_name: str, last_name: str, ssn: str):
    student = Student(first_name, last_name, ssn)
    my_school.students.append(student)
    db.update(
        {"students": [asdict(student) for student in my_school.students]},
        doc_ids=[1],
    )


@app.command()
def list_all():
    print(db.get(doc_id=1))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    db = TinyDB("school_db.json")
    if not db.get(doc_id=1):
        print("init")
        my_school = School("my_school")
        db.insert(asdict(my_school))
    my_school = School.from_dict(db.get(doc_id=1))
    app()
```

you can use it in the console by entering:

`python school.py add-student bruno mars 23gs44g5`

and then

`python school.py list-all`

inside the program folder you will see a "data.json" file. there you have all your data in a human readable and very interchangeable form

good luck